# Editable TableView with Core Data

Tags: core-data, ios4, uitableview

I'm working on my first app at the moment and I'm very, very confused at the moment.  I bet this is too much to ask for (and too specific), but I'm trying to make an app with folders, and when the user taps on an edit button, a separate view would come up that would contain a tableview that would already have editing enabled.  (The view is a UITableViewController to let the user manage their folders)

Also the user would be able to both add, delete, and rearrange his/her folders without tapping another button. When the add button is pressed a new view would come up in which the user types in the name of the new folder.  For now I don't care if the folders display in another part of the app or that that they can hold things, just about what I said above.

To make this already confusing request even MORE confusing, I want everything to be saved with Core Data.  You can probably see why I'm confused...

NOTE: I have already worked out how to add items (and save them), just not with custom names giving by user.

I know this is a lot, but can someone help?  Any sort of help or links to tutorials is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make everything custom. I dont know of any example or tutorials that demonstrate how to create "folders".

You can always programmatically create folders in the Documents directory of your app, and show them virtually in a UITableView. And if the user creates a "file", store that file in the respective folder. I am not sure how you would implement CoreData into that method though.

Apple has quite a few examples on how to use UITableView as well as CoreData. You can try source code sites like [Github](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).